# Matrix differentiation for the trace of matrix multiplication of Hadamard product

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, trace, hadamard-product

I struggle with taking the derivative of the following equation:

$\frac{∂}{∂B}Tr(A(B⊙C))$

where A,B,C are matrices, $Tr(.)$ is the trace of a matrix, and ⊙ is the Hadamard product.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you worked out the derivative with respect to a single entry $b_{ij}$ of $B$?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I want the final result to have the same dimension as matrix B. But I cannot achieve it!

Comment: Linearity of the derivative guarantees that you will be able to write the derivative of any function as a tensor. But that doesn't mean the tensor has a "nice" form!

Comment: Actually, this equation comes from my optimization problem which has the constraint of $B⊙C=0$ and $A$ acts as a lagrange multiplier. The dimension of the derivative needs to be the same as $B$. You mean this constraint cannot be met?!

Comment: Yes it can. The result will be a matrix whose $ij$-th entry is the $\frac{\partial}{\partial b_{ij}}$ derivative of your function.

Comment: I think the derivative is $A^T⊙C$. I want to be sure. Please let me know if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trace is equivalent to the inner/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,X:Y={\rm tr}(X^TY)$. 

And the Hadamard and Frobenius products commute, $X\odot Y:Z=X:Y\odot Z$.

So the function can be written in a form that's simple to differentiate
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A^T:C\odot B \cr
   &= A^T\odot C:B \cr\cr
df &= A^T\odot C:dB \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B} &= A^T\odot C \cr\cr
}$$